# How to list all commands available from $PATH

Tags: shell, path, command, executable

I would like to list all commands available in `$PATH`.

Any idea ?

Comment: `printf '%s\n' ${PATH//:/\/* }`

Comment: You can install `dmenu_path` from `suckless-tools`, a very nice little application

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick onliner that will complete the task as long as you have the rights to view the folders.

`for pathitem in $(echo $PATH | sed -e 's/:/ /g'); do echo $pathitem; ls -la $pathitem; echo ""; done`

This code will also display the path above the listing and a space underneath it, similar to completing a `ls -laR`

Comment: while this would be close, it lists all *files* in each $PATH directory; maybe there are some files there that aren't executable, and thus shouldn't be considered "commands"

Comment: I was just trying to show a quick one liner for the general idea.